# Datomic for emacs/elisp

Tags: clojure, data-structures

Does emacs/elisp have something equivalent or similar to Clojure's datomic?

What I tried: google emacs datomic

fyi by datomic I'm referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datomic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that Datomic is a commercial-grade database system with a Datalog query language, good scalability and time traveling capabilities, this is rather unlikely. I'm only aware of two database systems written in Emacs Lisp, [BBDB](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryBbdb) (which is just lots of code for serializing contact data to Lisp vectors) and [Elfeed's solution](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/09/09/) (which actually resembles one).

None of these even manage reaching SQLite levels of usability, so hoping for an even better solution that can be used in a distributed way is a waste of time.  You're best off with shelling out to a script doing the hard work.

edit: If you're looking for something that be ported and is similar in spirit, Picolisp has [Pilog](https://software-lab.de/doc/tut.html#pilog) with Prolog-like query language and [Datascript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript) is someone's interpretation of Datomic with a JS interface.